# fix artifacts in screen space reflections

Tags: graphics, 3d, shader, directx, hlsl

I am trying to implement SSR (screen space reflections). I managed to get a basic effect, but there are some artifacts as you can see from the images and the video below. First of all I would like to solve these visual problems and then I would like to try to improve the performance of the algorithm if possible.

SSR artifacts: https://youtu.be/LFBAJHa_mFM

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

My SSR implementation is based on this [tutorial](https://lettier.github.io/3d-game-shaders-for-beginners/screen-space-reflection.html).

Below you can find the code of the pixel shader that generates the reflection map (or reflected UV map) and here you can find the [full implementation](https://github.com/GiacomoGarbin/ScreenSpaceReflectionsDemo). As you can see it is practical identical to the code of the tutorial ([screen-space-reflection.frag](https://github.com/lettier/3d-game-shaders-for-beginners/blob/master/demonstration/shaders/fragment/screen-space-reflection.frag)) except for few changes:

- I don't store the 3D position of each pixel in an off-screen texture, but I reconstruct the 3D position from the view space depth in the function `GetFullViewPosition`.
- When I transform the fragment NDC into texture coordinates, I multiply by `float2(+0.5f, -0.5f)` instead of `float2(+0.5f, +0.5f)`.
- I added a check that stops ray tracing if the current position is out of screen space.

**SSRReflectionsMapComputePS.hlsl**

```
cbuffer ConstantBuffer : register(b0)
{
    float4   gFrustumFarCorner[4];
    float4x4 gProj;
};

struct VertexOut
{
    float4 PositionH  : SV_POSITION;
    float3 ToFarPlane : TEXCOORD0;
    float2 TexCoord   : TEXCOORD1;
};

Texture2D gNormalDepthMap : register(t0);
SamplerState gNormalDepthSamplerState : register(s2);

float3 GetFullViewPosition(float2 uv, float z)
{
    // bilinear interpolation
    float4 p0 = lerp(gFrustumFarCorner[0], gFrustumFarCorner[3], uv.x);
    float4 p1 = lerp(gFrustumFarCorner[1], gFrustumFarCorner[2], uv.x);
    float3 ToFarPlane = lerp(p0.xyz, p1.xyz, 1 - uv.y);

    // reconstruct full view space position (x,y,z)
    // find t such that p = t*pin.tofarplane
    // p.z = t*pin.tofarplane.z ==> t = p.z / pin.tofarplane.z
    return (z / ToFarPlane.z) * ToFarPlane;
}

float3 GetFullViewPosition(float2 uv)
{
    float4 NormalDepth = gNormalDepthMap.SampleLevel(gNormalDepthSamplerState, uv, 0);
    return GetFullViewPosition(uv, NormalDepth.w);
}

// https://lettier.github.io/3d-game-shaders-for-beginners/screen-space-reflection.html
// https://github.com/lettier/3d-game-shaders-for-beginners/blob/master/demonstration/shaders/fragment/screen-space-reflection.frag

float4 main(VertexOut pin) : sv_target
{
    // view space normal and depth (z-coord) of this pixel
    float4 normaldepth = gNormalDepthMap.SampleLevel(gNormalDepthSamplerState, pin.TexCoord, 0);

    float3 n = normaldepth.xyz;
    float pz = normaldepth.w;

    //float3 p = (pz / pin.tofarplane.z) * pin.tofarplane;
    float3 p = GetFullViewPosition(pin.TexCoord, pz);

    float maxdistance = 100;
    float resolution = 1;
    int   steps = 10;
    float thickness = 0.5f;

    float2 texsize;
    gNormalDepthMap.GetDimensions(texsize.x, texsize.y);
    float2 texcoord = pin.PositionH.xy / texsize;

    float3 positionfrom = p;
    float3 positionfromunit = normalize(positionfrom);
    float3 normal = normalize(n);
    float3 pivot = normalize(reflect(positionfromunit, normal));

    float3 positionto = positionfrom;
    float4 uv = 0;

    float3 viewstart = positionfrom + pivot * 0;
    float3 viewend = positionfrom + pivot * maxdistance;

    float4 fragstart = float4(viewstart, 1);
    fragstart = mul(gProj, fragstart);
    fragstart.xy /= fragstart.w;
    fragstart.xy = fragstart.xy * float2(+0.5f, -0.5f) + 0.5f;
    fragstart.xy *= texsize;

    float4 fragend = float4(viewend, 1);
    fragend = mul(gProj, fragend);
    fragend.xy /= fragend.w;
    fragend.xy = fragend.xy * float2(+0.5f, -0.5f) + 0.5f;
    fragend.xy *= texsize;

    float2 frag = fragstart.xy;
    uv.xy = frag / texsize;

    float deltax = fragend.x - fragstart.x;
    float deltay = fragend.y - fragstart.y;
    float usex = abs(deltax) >= abs(deltay) ? 1 : 0;
    float delta = lerp(abs(deltay), abs(deltax), usex) * clamp(resolution, 0, 1);
    float2 increment = float2(deltax, deltay) / max(delta, 0.001f);

    float search0 = 0;
    float search1 = 0;

    int hit0 = 0;
    int hit1 = 0;

    float viewdistance = viewstart.z;
    float depth = thickness;

    for (int i = 0; i < int(delta); ++i)
    {
        frag += increment;
        uv.xy = frag / texsize;

        // do not sample outside the screen space
        if (any(uv.xy < float2(0, 0)) || any(uv.xy > float2(1, 1))) break;

        positionto = GetFullViewPosition(uv.xy);

        search1 = lerp((frag.y - fragstart.y) / deltay, (frag.x - fragstart.x) / deltax, usex);
        search1 = clamp(search1, 0, 1);

        viewdistance = (viewstart.z * viewend.z) / lerp(viewend.z, viewstart.z, search1);
        depth = viewdistance - positionto.z;

        if (depth > 0 && depth < thickness)
        {
            hit0 = 1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            search0 = search1;
        }
    }

    search1 = search0 + ((search1 - search0) / 2);

    steps *= hit0;

    for (int i = 0; i < steps; ++i)
    {
        frag = lerp(fragstart.xy, fragend.xy, search1);
        uv.xy = frag / texsize;

        // do not sample outside the screen space
        if (any(uv.xy < float2(0, 0)) || any(uv.xy > float2(1, 1))) break;

        positionto = GetFullViewPosition(uv.xy);

        viewdistance = (viewstart.z * viewend.z) / lerp(viewend.z, viewstart.z, search1);
        depth = viewdistance - positionto.z;

        if (depth > 0 && depth < thickness)
        {
            hit1 = 1;
            search1 = search0 + ((search1 - search0) / 2);
        }
        else
        {
            float temp = search1;
            search1 = search1 + ((search1 - search0) / 2);
            search0 = temp;
        }
    }

    float visibility = hit1 *
        (1 - max(dot(-positionfromunit, pivot), 0)) *
        (1 - clamp(depth / thickness, 0, 1)) *
        (1 - clamp(length(positionto - positionfrom) / maxdistance, 0, 1)) *
        (uv.x < 0 || uv.x > 1 ? 0 : 1) *
        (uv.y < 0 || uv.y > 1 ? 0 : 1);

    return float4(uv.xy, 0, saturate(visibility));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with artifacts when I implemented SSR. I had all my g-buffer textures set up as `LINEAR` min and mag filtering. Changing them to `NEAREST` fixed the artifacts you’re seeing at the back of the skull.